# Detect the uppercase with Regex Yahoo Pipes

Tags: regex, pipe, yahoo

I have trouble with Regex. I would like to detect the uppercase and put a #in front. And also remove the spaces...

Example: `Chris Pratt talks Jurassic World`

```
#ChrisPratt talks #JurassicWorld
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The regex to find two consecutive uppercased words seperated by a space would be:

```
/([A-Z][a-z]*)\s([A-Z][a-z]*)/g
```